# How to authenticate own smtp client to send messages through others servers using mx records? C#

Tags: c#, email, authentication, smtp

There is a file with receiver email and sender email. My own smtp server receive messages and save them to files. How to send message to receiver through the next servers? If I understood correctly I should find the mx records by domain and try to send email. But the issue is how to authenticate my smtp-client considering that most of smtp servers require the authentication? 
Please help me to understand if I am right and how to managed with.

Comment: are you trying to send the message to those servers, or are you trying to send a message through those server.  Because if its the later you, most of the time will need to have an account with them to do so

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am trying to send message to those servers.  Can I do it without having account? If yes then how?

Comment: What do you mean server, what protocol are you trying to use email not ftp right? Open up an smtp client connect to your server using your email credentials and just address it to who you want to send to

Comment: No, you do not understand me. I do not have an account on the server where I try to send email. I only have email addresses of receiver and sender. I found the mx records by the receiver domain name and I want to send the message to one of them. There is a simple scheme what I mean: 
some server sends message -> my server receives the message and saves it to the db-> my client finds mx records by the receiver domain name and trying to send it to the foreground server
The question is can I send the message without authentication?

Comment: Okay, well if its your smtp server, you can configure it to do what ever you want. so in theory yes you can create send a message without authenticating, but it's not a recommened practice because then anyone could send an unauthenticated message from your server.  So instead create an account NoReply@YourServer and create credentials for that account and then use that generic account to authenticate all messages sent.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: But I actually meant how to send messages without authentication on the  foreground servers? I bad understand you in general.

Comment: For example I have: receiver email address - test@outlook.com and sender - test2@gmail.com. I found the next mx records by receiver domain:
1) google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
2) google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
and then I am trying to send the message to the first of them. It has priority is equal to 10. But the server require the authentication. I do not have required credentials  that is why I ask can I do that without authentication? I expect that this server will send the message to receiver.